# Item not removed from DataGrid when removing from ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, prism, observablecollection

I'm struggling to get the datagrid updated when I remove items from my ObservableCollection. When I remove them, the items in the ObservableCollection that is binded to the DataGrid are removed correctly but they still appear in the DataGrid.

This is my view:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ContactsList" Margin="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

(columns are populated in the code-behind).

This is my view-model:

```
public class ContactsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly IConfigurationContactsService contactsService;

    private readonly DelegateCommand<object> deleteContactCommand;

    private ObservableCollection<Contact> contactsCollection;
    private ICollectionView contactsView;

    public ContactsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IConfigurationContactsService contactsService, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.contactsService = contactsService;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        this.deleteContactCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.DeleteContact, this.CanDeleteContact);

        this.contactsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(contactsService.GetContacts());
        this.contactsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.contactsCollection);
    }

    public ICollectionView ContactsView
    {
        get { return this.contactsView; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get { return this.contactsCollection; }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteContactCommand
    {
        get { return this.deleteContactCommand; }
    }

    private void DeleteContact(object ignore)
    {
        IList<Contact> selectedContacts = contactsService.GetSelectedContacts();
        foreach (Contact contact in selectedContacts)
        {
            if (contact != null)
            {
                contactsService.DeleteContact(contact);
            }
        }
        SetProperty<ObservableCollection<Contact>>(ref this.contactsCollection, new ObservableCollection<Contact>(contactsService.GetContacts()), "Contacts");
        // After this, the observable collection is updated correctly, but the datagrid does not delete the items.
    }
    private bool CanDeleteContact(object ignored)
    {
        return contactsService.GetSelectedContacts().Any();
    }       
}
```

I can't see where the error is. Can anyone spot the error? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

There is one peculiarity on this view. There is a Main View with a toolbar (where the delete button is), and a ContentTab region that holds two views: View A, View B). The DataGrid is located in View A, and all thre views (A, B and MainView) have the same viewmodel: ContactsViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you binding to the ObservableCollection when you have a ICollectionView property?. Anyway, this should refresh the binding to the ObservableCollection:

```
private void DeleteContact(object ignore)
{
    IList<Contact> selectedContacts = contactsService.GetSelectedContacts();
    foreach (Contact contact in selectedContacts)
    {
        if (contact != null)
        {
            contactsService.DeleteContact(contact);
        }
    }
    contactsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(contactsService.GetContacts());
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Contacts");
}
```

If the DataGrid doesn't get updated you need to verify that the contactsService.GetContacts() method returns the items that you expect it to return.

**Edit:** You also need to make sure the view binds to the same instance of the view model in which the DeleteContact method is executed. Put a breakpoint in the constructor of the view model and make sure that it gets hit only once. Then you know that there is only one instance created and that you bind to this one.

Comment: Still doesn't get updated, and the contactsService.GetContacts() returns exactly the items that I expect. :/

Comment: Are you sure that you are binding to the Contacts property then? If you set a breakpoint in the Contacts getter, does it get hit when the view is loaded and after the DeleteContact method has been executed?

Comment: It gets hit when the view is loaded, but it doesn't get hit after the DeleteContacts method has beed exectued.

Comment: And you are sure that you only have single instance of the ContactsViewModel class and that the DeleteContact method doesn't throw any exceptions?

Comment: DeleteContact doesn´t throw any exception but how can I check that I have only one instance of the ContactsViewModel class?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in its constructor and make sure that it only get hit once. I think you will have to provide a full reproducible sample if you want any further help on this. It's hard to say what you are doing wrong without having access to your code.

Comment: Okey. That's the issue: The ContactsViewModel constructor is hit three times (I am guessing one for MainView, one for View A and the other one for Vieb B). That is gonna be the issue, but I still doesn't know how to fix this. I am using Prism

Comment: You obviously need to make sure that the view binds to the same instance of the view model in which the DeleteContact method is executed.

Comment: But I shouldn't have three instances of the ViewModel. I should have just one View model and all thre views binded to the same ViewModel. How can I do this?

Comment: It depends on how and where you create the views. But this is a different question really.

Comment: I'll post it in another question then. If you want to state your answer in a new answer I'd mark it as the correct one. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Observable collection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you don't have to do that again:

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts{ get;}


private void DeleteContact(object ignore)
{
    IList<Contact> selectedContacts = contactsService.GetSelectedContacts();
    foreach (Contact contact in selectedContacts)
    {
        if (contact != null)
        {
            contactsService.DeleteContact(contact);
            Contacts.Remove(contact);// HERE IS THE CHANGE
        }
    }
}
```

You only have to remove the old items, and add new items. No need for another instance.

**EDIT:**

To add new items, do the following:

```
Contacts.Add(newContact);
```

**EDIT EDIT:**

You might have to modify your deleting a little bit, try this:

```
Contacts.Remove(Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c=c.Id == contact.Id)); // HERE IS THE CHANGE
```

I don't know if you have an ID property in your contact class, if not then use something else to find the correct contact, eg. Name or Last name

Comment: Hi Nawed, I tried your suggestion but same issue. The contact is deleted from the collection but it is not deleted from the DataGrid. Is there maybe an issue with the binding? But I can't spot the error.

Comment: @chincheta73, Seems like you have a contactService, and you also delete the contact from there, but is the Contact deleted at the contactServer or at Contacts ? Can you confirm that the contact is removed from Contacts ?

Comment: I just made a test project and I used `ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"` and it worked

Comment: Yes. The contact is deleted from Contacts (and of course, also from the contactsService). Looking at the traces of the binding, the Mode is One Way, and the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

Comment: The binding is one way correct, but you also only have a getter for the observablecollection

Comment: Do you mean I also need a setter for the observablecollection? Or just with the getter is correct?

Comment: No, no setter needed. The getter only is correct, thus only oneway binding

Comment: There is one peculiarity on this view. There is a Main View with a toolbar (where the delete button is), and a ContentTab region that holds two views: View A, View B). The DataGrid is located in View A, and all thre views (A, B and MainView) have the same viewmodel: ContactsViewModel. Can this situation cause that malfunction?

Comment: Not really, as long as your DataGrid is bound to the Contacts collection and you see the correct contacts then it should also work when you remove. How and where do you instantiate the Contacts collection and add contacts to it ?

Comment: The Contacts collections is instantiated in the ContactsViewModel constructor (see the main post), and there are some contacts created on the ContactsService constructor for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes but in your `ContactsViewModel` you use `Contacts {get{return contactsCollection;}}`, which was wrong. You should only use `Contacts {get;}` and populate that collection only. But if you really want to do it the other way around the you have to use OnPropertyChanged("contactsCollection") every time there is a change in the contact collection

Comment: If I do Contacts {get;} I got this error: ''Contacts.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.' I also tried to define get and set and still doesn't work.